# What type of grease to prevent seat post sticking?

Tags: seatpost, preventative-maintenance

What type of grease should I buy specifically to prevent the seat post from getting stuck in the seat tube? I believe its aluminum.  Is there all-purpose grease that I can use for other parts of the bike?  This is an older, inexpensive bike that I need to last for another few years.

Comment: If you want to be as cautious as possible you can go to an auto parts place and get "anti-seize compound".  But that's not a grease you should use other places.

Comment: Is it a concern that grease may interfere with getting the seat to stay up?  If so, would it be better to have a quarterly or monthly maintenance task, "remove the seat post and then just put it back in, and maybe twist it around a little before locking it down"?

Comment: @compton No, grease will not make your seatpost slide down. If it's the correct size and it's clamped properly, it'll stay put, no matter how much you grease it.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak You have much experience with BSO?

Comment: @Paparazzi Irrelevant. A clamp is a clamp. If it's gripping the seatpost like it's supposed to, it won't move. Otherwise, it'll move whether or not you greased it.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak Grease is lubricant.

Comment: What's wrong with the seat post getting stuck in the tube? Are you intending for other people to ride the bike? Are you worried that you're going to get taller or shorter and hence need to adjust it (surely only a concern for children or the elderly)? Otherwise I'd have thought that once you've got it set to the right height you never want it to move again?!

Comment: @AndyT wouldn't different shoes, pedals, saddle require the seat height to be changed even when it was perfect before? Not to speak of replacing the seat post itself. Maintenance also may require the seatpost to be remmoved; for instance, something as trivial as letting water drip out of the frame.

Comment: @AndyT - Flexibility can change over time may require changes to seat height (e.g.,  hamstring flexibility). Injuries may also require a change in fit.

Comment: A stuck seatpost will also lower the resale value, nobody wants to buy a bike with a stuck seatpost.

Answer (score 5):

I use basic thick grease from an auto parts store. The can says multi-purpose waterproof grease. It's thick like a cream, or butter and dirt cheap. You only need a small amount.

Comment: You can buy "Bike specific grease" from a bike shop. It comes in small tubes rather than large jars so you don't need to pay any attention to the thousand different types of grease in an auto shop (high pressure, high temperature, long life, fast vs slow bearing surface etc) and you don;t have to buy a life time supply -  but you pay a premium what is essentially a standard grease in a small tube.

Comment: The tubs of park grease cost barely twice as much as the tube, (15 bucks or so) so might as well get one.

Comment: @afc welcome to [bicycles.SE]. Thanks for your answer. Could you make it a little more specific with regard to the grease? I understood that there are plenty of different greases for automotive parts stores. Taking the [tour] might be good if you like to know more about procedures on SE.

Answer (score 3):

Carbon paste (AKA Carbon Prep) would be better than grease.

Its designed to provide grip so carbon components don't have to be over tightened, and is designed to work with metal on carbon and protect against galvanic corrosion. Exactly what is needed to stop a metal seat post sticking in metal frame.

Another thing that will prevent seizing is regular (monthly or 6 monthly depending on riding conditions) loosen the seat, give it a twist and tighten it up.

Comment: Carbon paste is only required/better than grease if you have a delicate frame and can’t get the seat post tight enough without violating the maximum allowed torque. Otherwise it’s just expensive. If you don’t have any problems with a loose seat post, cheap grease will do.

Comment: A tube of Finish Line Fiber Grip costs 10 EUR and, used appropriately (sparingly), will last a decade or more. I have tens of different oils, greases, thread lockers and various other bike/motorbike/car/machine/workshop chemicals, don't see a reason to skip here. Some people like to get by on just one kind of grease, use engine oil or ATF for whatever purposes, etc. For these people, a regular grease would do as a seatpost lube. I wouldn't use one with special anti-friction additives (like Teflon or MoS2).

Answer (score 3):

The only time that there's really only one right answer is if the frame and seatpost are dissimilar metals (aluminum/steel, titanium/aluminum, titanium/steel). In this scenario, you should ABSOLUTELY use an anti-seize compound. Something like Park's ASC-1 is perfect for this. The anti-seize compound has zinc in it, which acts as a sacrificial metal to prevent the frame and seatpost from corroding and bonding to each other.

For other materials, you can still use anti-sieze compound, but you don't need to. A thin layer of grease will work in most cases. In the event that you're having problems with a seatpost slipping even when clamped, then go with an anti-slip compound, like Park's SAC-2.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense in theory, but my own limited experience tells otherwise. I ride the same titanium frame mountain bike for the last 15+ years, for the seatpost I used to use regular grease, later Carbon Grip. Never saw any signs of corrosion.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the Park Tool grease that virtually every bike shop carries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any grease you want. Bike grease, automotive axle grease, organic extra-virgin coconut oil, they'll all work for this task. But if you plan to do any further maintenance on your bike (and you should), then buy some bicycle-specific grease, because you'll need it later.

Comment: EVCO smells nice :)